# How to Extract Value From Timestamp object & date time object array

Tags: php, arrays, object

**How To Get Date From Below Object**

```
Google\Cloud\Core\Timestamp Object
(

    [value:Google\Cloud\Core\Timestamp:private] => DateTimeImmutable Object
        (
            [date] => 2020-02-11 05:17:40.679449
            [timezone_type] => 2
            [timezone] => Z
        )

    [nanoSeconds:Google\Cloud\Core\Timestamp:private] => 679449000
)
```

Comment: what Kind of format it is? do you want to get Date and time from timestamp?

Comment: i am looking for this format dd-mm-yyyy

Comment: extract and combine using `new Date()`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In the object `Google\Cloud\Core\Timestamp`, `get` fucntion returns an instance of php `DateTime` class. so you can do something like this:

```
 echo $timestampObject->get()->format('d-m-Y');
```

Source: https://github.com/googleapis/google-cloud-php-core/blob/master/tests/Unit/TimestampTest.php